# Convert local time to UTC for all rows postgres

Tags: postgresql

Currently my table has stored the time in local time (+11:00 Sydney Australia) and I would like to convert all the values in the time column to UTC time.

The table format looks like:

| Time | Suburb |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 00:00 | Cheltenham |
| 2022-10-31 23:59 | Epping |

What I am hoping to get is:

| Time | Suburb |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-30 14:00 | Cheltenham |
| 2022-10-31 14:00 | Epping |

Is there a way that I can update all the rows in the time column? I have tried using the subquery

```
UPDATE time_table 
SET    time = (Select timezone('Australia/Sydney', time) from time_table)
```

However, it errors with "more than one row returned by a subquery used in expression". I realise that the subquery can only return 1 result, however is there a way where I can update all the rows in the Time column?

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

Comment: What is the data type for the `"time"  field?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the data type of the column is `timestamp` (without time zone), you could

```
UPDATE tab
SET time = time AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

First, the timestamp is interpreted as Australian time and converted to the corresponding `timestamp with time zone`, then we get the `timestamp` that a UTC clock shows at that time.